# Can I install ElementaryOS the same way as ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation

So I recently downloaded ubuntu with a specific tutorial because I use legacy mode to boot up windows and linux, but I haven't found any tutorials to download ElementaryOS with legacy/bios mode, so since ElementaryOS is based off Ubuntu, would I be able to download it the same way?

I've already created the install drive with rufus, and I plan to download ElementaryOS on a seperate partition, but I also plan on using EasyBCD to correctly duel boot.

tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-iSAyiicyQY&ab_channel=KskRoyal

If anyone knows any tutorials for ElementaryOS in legacy/bios mode, please share, any advice would be appreciated.